# how to get data between \/media\/345333434.m3u8 usinpreg_match_all?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to get data between / and .m3u8. For example if $get_data holds a url like this :
 **/media/345333434.m3u8** i want to print out only 345333434. My current code wont do that ! could any one tell me how to fix it.Thanks

```
preg_match_all("#media\/([^<]+).m3u8#", $get_data[$i], $fooM3u8);

print_r($fooM3u8[1]);
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/152162).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a regular expression, from the [PHP docs for basename](https://www.php.net/basename):

$path = '/media/345333434.m3u8';
$info = pathinfo($path);
$file_name =  basename($path, '.' . $info['extension']);

echo $file_name; // outputs '345333434'

Comment: thanks for reply . But get_data holds those extra backslashes in url it didn't show when i posted it here! [code]media\/345333434.m3u8 [/code].How to deal with those extra backslashes ?